# thenReturn overloaded method has alternatives - how can this be resolved?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito, scalatest

I have a function within a class like:

```
def saveToken(token: Token, ttl: Instant, client: Client, partner: Partner, info: Info): Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]]
```

and `EitherErrorsOr` is :

```
type EitherErrorsOr[A] = scala.Either[Errors, A]
```

`Errors` is our internal `Errors` class

When I try to mock `saveToken` as follows:

```
when(
      mockService.saveToken(
        any(), any(), any(), any(), any()
    )
  ).thenReturn(Right(NoOpVal).toFut)
```

then I get an error such as:

```
overloaded method value thenReturn with alternatives:
  (x$1: scala.concurrent.Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]],x$2: scala.concurrent.Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]]*)org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[scala.concurrent.Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]]] <and>
  (x$1: scala.concurrent.Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]])org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[scala.concurrent.Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]]]
 cannot be applied to (scala.concurrent.Future[scala.util.Right[Nothing,NoOp]])
      ).thenReturn(Right(NoOpVal).toFut)
```

Why does `thenReturn` come up with so many alternatives?

Note:
`Done` is our internal class that signifies that an operation is complete ,
`toFut` converts to a `Future` object, `NoOpVal` is just some type created for testing purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is in the return type. The return type of the method is `Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]]`, which is `Future[Either[Errors, Done]]`.

Let's now analyze the type of `Right(NoOpVal).toFut`. The implementation of [`Right`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/util/Either.scala#L471) is:

```scala
final case class Right[+A, +B](b: B) extends Either[A, B] {
  def isLeft = false
  def isRight = true
}
```

Let's assume that `NoOpVal` is of type `A`, when calling `Right(NoOpVal)` you get an instance of type `Right[Nothing, A]`, because you didn't supply the first generics to `Right`.

`Right[Nothing, A]` cannot be casted into `Future[EitherErrorsOr[Done]]`.

How do you solve that? Easy just do:

```scala
when(mockService.saveToken(any(), any(), any(), any(), any()))
    .thenReturn(Right[Errors, Done](NoOpVal).toFut)
```

and make sure `NoOpVal` extends `Done`.